# Example of how to use msilib to create a .msi file from a python module

Tags: python, windows, windows-installer

Can anyone give me an example of how to use python's [msilib](http://docs.python.org/library/msilib.html) standard library module to create a msi file from a custom python module?

For example, let's say I have a custom module called cool.py with the following code

```
class Cool(object):
    def print_cool(self):
        print "cool"
```

and I want to create an msi file using msilib that will install cool.py in python's site-packages directory.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write a distutils setup script for your module, then you can do

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

and an msi-installer will be created for your module.

See also http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.command.bdist_msi

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding: think of MS CAB Files as archives like `.zip`-Files. Now it is possible to put anything in such an archive, like your `cool.py`. But i think you mentioned that python source, since you want it executed, otherwise just use an archiver like zip, no need to use `mslib`.

If i am right then you first need to convert your script into an executable using something like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) or [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).