# Creating Setup for Windows Systems

Tags: python, python-3.x, window

This is the question: How to create a setup file(.msi) from a .py file? I have a little script but I need an installer to use it with "InstallSimple" program wich will install another applications.

I tried with pyinstaller but it supports 2.3-2.7 versions and I have an script for 3.3 version.

Comment: Have you tried [msilib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html)?  Here's another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/728589/981380) from SO.

Comment: @dinesh: Although you can make msi files with msi-lib, it doesn't contain software to actually make an msi file out of your script. It is therefore the wrong solution. However, software that creates an msi-file is also included in stdlib, namely distutils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an `.msi` file you need to use [distutils](http://docs.python.org/3.3/distutils/index.html). The essential procedure there is to create a `setup.py` file with information about your script, and you can then run `python setup.py bdist_msi` and it will create an `.msi` file for you.

However, using only this will create an `.msi`-file for your Python script, but it will require you to install Python on the computer first. This is probably not what you want. To solve that you can create an `.exe`-file from your script with [cx_Freeze](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/). cx_Freeze can in turn use distutils to make the `.msi` file. There is an example [here](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) ? According to the latest docs [cx_Freeze 4.3.1 documentation](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), it supports python3.